# Shared FTP folder creation

Tags: debian, ftp, share

I have installed ProFTPd and configured users' directories privately. I would like to make also a shared folder, that can access all the users. How can I do this?

Comment: mkdir /home/shared_dir ; groupadd -g 1500 ftpall && chown root:ftpall /home/shared_dir ; chmod g+s /home/shared_dir and put everyuser you want in this group

Comment: I have jailed users to his home directories, so a user can not see this shared_dir. How can I make it accessible?

Comment: if you have many users to manage, you can use automount to mount /home/shared_dir in user home directories, mount --bind /home/pippo/shared_dir

Comment: correct command mount --bind /home/shared_dir /home/pippo/shared_dir

Comment: Thanks a lot! If you add this as a new individual answer, I can give you some extra points! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To archive what you want to do, you can do it in this way:

```
mkdir /home/shared_dir
groupadd -g 1500 ftpall && chown root:ftpall /home/shared
chmod g+s /home/shared_dir
```

Now, if your ftp users are in chroot jail, you can mount the shared the directory inside the user home:

```
mount --bind /home/shared_dir /home/pippo/shared_dir
```